# Largest range of a list of five integers in which the mean, median and mode are consecutive integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, descriptive-statistics

> A student notices that in a list of five integers, the mean, median and mode were consecutive integers in ascending order. What is the largest range possible for these five integers and why? Please explain clearly.

When I first saw the question I thought that one of the integers (a mean, median, mode integer) had to be $x-1$, one  had to be $x$ and  one $x+1$. But I do not know which is which and how to find out the largest range possible

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: *"When I first saw the question I thought that one of the integers ( a mean, median, mode integer) had to be x-1,one had to be x and one x+1"*

i am glad you were able to see that

Comment: The next step is figuring out what it _means_ that the mode is $x+1$, in terms of the values of the five numbers. Once you've done that, you may want to puzzle out what it means in practice that the median is $x$.

Comment: I actually have the answer-7-but I don't understand how the author got it. I now know that the mean is x-1,the median x and the mode x+1. But I don't understand how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Gerry's answer...

OK, I'll start from the beginning. Let's call the numbers $r,s,t,u$ and $v$ with $r\le s\le t\le u\le v$. The median is $x$, so $t=x$. The mode is $x+1$, so $u=x+1$. We need more than one with this value, so $v=x+1$ as well. The mean is $x-1$, so \begin{align}\frac{r+s+t+u+v}{5}&=x-1\\r+s+t+u+v&=5x-5\end{align}

The range is $v-r$ and we have already determined that $v=x+1$ so to maximize the range we need to minimize $r$. In order to do that we maximize $s$, so $s=x-1$. Now we just need to find $r$. Let $r=x-a$, then substitute into the above equation and solve for $a$:
\begin{align}r+s+t+u+v&=5x-5\\(x-a)+(x-1)+x+(x+1)+(x+1)&=5x-5\\5x-a+1&=5x-5\\-a&=-6\\a&=6\end{align}
So the maximum range is $v-r=(x+1)-(x-a)=1+a=1+6=7$

Comment: But how do we get what a is without knowing what x is?

Comment: @ezekiel It doesn't matter what $x$ is. In fact, $x$ can be any integer. The question only asks for the maximum difference between the lowest and highest of the five numbers.

Comment: What I don't understand is the v-r subtraction and how you get 5x-5.

Comment: @ezekiel I updated my post with more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Call the five integers $r\le s\le t\le u\le v$. The mean is $x-1$; that gives us the equation, $$r+s+t+u+v=5x-5$$ The median is $x$; that tells us $t=x$. The mode is $x+1$; that tells us $u=v=x+1$. Putting these together, you get an equation relating $r,s,x$, and you get $s<x$. The range is $v-r$, which is $x+1-r$. Now putting these together, you can work out all the possible values of $r$, and then pick out the one that maximizes the range.

Can you fill in the details?

Comment: Sorry,but I cannot understand this answer as well because what you have written is nearly the same as what my author has written. Can you please solve it in a different way?

Comment: You have to put some work into this too, you know. So, where exactly does your understanding stop? Are you OK with the 1st sentence?

Comment: Yes, but I think your last sentence of the second paragraph was a bit weird because  r could have an infinite number of values

Comment: If you look at all the constraints, $r$ can only have finitely many values (for any given $x$). The smaller $r$ is, the bigger $s$ is, but $s<x$, so that limits $r$ on the down side – and the up side doesn't matter, since it's the down side of $r$ that determines the range (and, anyway, $r$ is bounded above by $s$ and hence by $x$).

Comment: But why is it so?

Comment: Why is WHAT so?

Comment: Why doesn't the up side matter?

Comment: The range is $x+1-r$. Making $r$ big isn't going to make that quantity big, so the up side doesn't matter.